# How to connect a primary key by primary key of the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: This is the ER diagram of that database]

I want to construct this database. Here in category table we give ID primary key of the category table to foreign key of the category table. I understood this and I done this part also but see in product table we want to give ID primary key of the product table to product table as a primary key so how to do that? This is my question? We can't able to use the same syntax in the foreign key. I want to done this in SQL server. So kindly anyone help me to do this part.

Comment: `create table product (id int primary key references product, ...` but I can't see anything useful coming from that

Comment: Why would the product table be any different from the category table in terms of how to handle the primary / foreign key relationship to itself?

Comment: hmm - it is a bad sign when you try to "use" a [commercial system](https://www.advantshop.com/pages/db-structure) whose website has not been updated in a decade as a starting point. One of their examples is `CREATE VIEW [Catalog].[view_GetCurrency] AS SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ...` - don't even bother IMO.

Comment: The official documentation is always a good place to start.

Comment: @SMor it's different because OP says the primary key must be a foreign key to itself. It makes no sense.

Comment: _primary key of the product table to product table as a primary key_ makes no sense. Are you trying to understand this picture of a data model based on those tiny lines and key symbols?

Answer (score 0):

The database looks ok apart from one thing:

One table, (product) has a 1:1-relation to itself. It makes no sense in any way.

1:1 relations are used between *different* tables and are great at times (customizations on 3:rd part systems etc)

What you probably want is a 1:n-relation to make one product act as a collection of other products, (also available as separate products). For this to work you must add a foregin-key field (nullable) in the product-table.

But that solution would probably be too limiting for the purpose above, since one product could only belong to one product. So what you want is a n:n relation. So what you need to do is create a *new table* as in:

```
product_part
============
product_id
part_product_id
```

This is called a *junction table* and both fields are used to make up the primary key.

However, junction tables may grow over time to regular tables as fields are added, so I would advice you to use a separate PK field (makes API-requests easier etc) as in:

```
product_part
============
id
product_id
part_product_id
position
qty
```

Hope this helps.